# connector of HP Universal Media Bay(HP ProLiant DL360 Gen9 server)

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant

I have a HP ProLiant DL360 Gen9 server which should support *HP Universal Media Bay*. How is it connected to motherboard? If I open up the server, then there is no connector for that:

[image: HP Universal Media Bay]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what's installed inside of your server, the chassis type and disk setup.

The cables come with the kit.

[Read the manual](http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c04566802-3.pdf).

[image]

[image]